# Collecting specific data from CSV file using Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm in need of some assistance with a MapReduce program. I have a CSV file with 15 total columns. I'm trying to extract data from two of the columns (Market and Amount Funded) based on the value (Year) of a third column.

As of now, my program outputs the data from the two columns (Market and Amount Funded) for each entry. What I would like for it to output is either the Total Amount Funded for each Market for a specified year or the Total Amount Funded for each Market for a specified range of years.

I'll post my mapper code below along with an example data entry. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

```
public class FundingMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
private Text market = new Text();
private Text amount = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
    CSVReader R = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line));

    String[] ParsedLine = R.readNext();
    R.close();

    amount.set(ParsedLine[15]);
    market.set(ParsedLine[3]);

    output.collect(market, amount);
}
}
```

`/organization/hashoff, #HASHOFF, |Digital Media|Internet|Social Media|, Digital Media, USA, CO, Denver, Denver, /funding-round/669d6203c0374e6cf0e8d10f75ba0b8a, debt_financing, 12/8/14, 2014-12, 2014-Q4, 2014, 455,000`

For the above entry, my program will output, with the proper headers, Digital Media and 455,000 for Market and Amount Funded, respectively. I'd like the program to output results based on the year or specified range of years.

Here's my job code as well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(FundingJob.class);

    conf.setJobName("Funding Data");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(FundingMapper.class);
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
    JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are outputting as key the market and as value the amount, I think you shoukd move to a year-market concatenation regarding the key. By having such a key, you will be able to generate a list of (key,value) pairs like this example one:

```
2014-DigitalMedia,455000
2014-OtherMarket,34500
2014-DigitalMedia,100000
2015-DigitalMedia,120000
2015-DigitalMedia,67000
2015-OtherMarket,15000
2015-OtherMarket,10000
...
```

Then a reducer class could get each tuple and aggregate the amount per key, resulting:

```
2014-DigitalMedia,555000
2014-OtherMarket,34500
2015-DigitalMedia,187000
2015-OtherMarket,25000
```

The code for the reducer could be something like:

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;

    while (values.hasNext()) {
        sum += values.next().get();
    }

    output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
```

In the main program you must add:

```
conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
```

Comment: This is a huge step in the right direction, so thank you! However, I believe that I need a combiner somewhere in my reducer as I'm getting the output that I've listed below for each market category. I'd like the total sum for each category for each year.                                                                           2015 Video   28,000,000 
2015 Video   24,000,000 
2015 Video   389,970 
2015 Video   2,000,000 
2015 Video  
2015 Video   30,000,000 
2015 Video   15,000,000